# Debugging .xccrashpoint

Tags: ios, xcode, crash-reports, xcode-organizer

I've got some logs on Xcode's Organizer but I don't know how to properly debug them. I've read Apple Documentation at [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AnalyzingCrashReports/AnalyzingCrashReports.html) by it doesn't tells me where the error/crash message is. It's hard to debug if you don't know what has caused it. When I try to open each log in Finder, it opens a .xccrashpoint file, not a standard crash log.

[image: Xcode Organizer]

Is there anyway to know the error message (as we received on previous crash reports)?

Comment: only debugging sessions will give you error messages. Crash report / crash dump won't provide this.

Comment: Why don't you award one of the answers - both of them are helpful.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I have stumbled on this recently too. What helped me was:

- right click on the crash -> show in finder
- copy the .xccrashpoint file somewhere
- rename the file extension from .xccrashpoint to .crash
- now Finder sees it as a folder and you can browse to the .crash file you need

Then you need to symbolicate the crash. There are several ways to do this, but the easiest I know is to:

- open Window -> Devices panel in xCode
- Click on the device (I had to plug in iPad) -> open device logs
- drag and drop the .crash file there
- sort by date, find your crash, the crash is now symbolicated

Answer (score 11):

Actually this file is a package and by right click on, and select

> Show Package Contents

you can see contents of it.

- **DistributionInfos->all->Logs**

You see the all reports file, then open them by "Console" application

Comment: It happens (quite often) that (buggy) Xcode displays a non symbolized version of the crash / stracktrace, despite i've the .dSYM package correctly located. The solution in that case is to enter the bundle (package content) and note that there are several .crash files for the very same crash. ONE OF THEM IS CORRECTLY SYMBOLICATED! (but Xcode ignores it and use the non symbolicated one)

Answer (score 0):

right-click on .xccrashpoint and select `Show Package Contents`

find `.crash` file you like (in some `Logs` folder you choose)

right-click on concrete .crash file and select -> `Open With` -> `Xcode`

and choose your project