# How do I view Apple App Store crash reports older than two weeks old?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, crash-reports

Yesterday, I had two crash reports in my Crash Log section of Organizer in Xcode.

Today, my Crashes section is empty and the crash reports are missing.

[image: empty state of Crash Log section of Organizer]

*(empty state of Crash Log section of Organizer)*

Xcode says,

> "No crash logs reported for this version in the last two weeks"

but I need access to the older crash reports which were there just yesterday.

How do access the older reports?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that Apple currently only supports a time frame of two weeks for crash stats. As per their [doc](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev861f46ea8)

> Xcode downloads the top crash reports—crash reports with the most
>   number of occurrences on unique devices—that occurred during the past
>   two weeks.

And if you would like to keep the downloaded log file for further analysis then you can found it by simply

`Right click on the crash report entry in Xcode's Organizer window and select "Show in Finder"`

**Or** usually, it will be available in the following path

```
~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Products/{your bundle id}/{your selected version number}/Crashes/AppStore/
```

You can use this `.xccrashpoint` package file for futhur analysis([more details..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32900063/debugging-xccrashpoint)).

**Note:** For more better crash issues with the detailed analysis, you can use this tool: [Fabric Crashlytics](https://fabric.io/kits/ios/crashlytics)

Hope this may help you